# How to create content from XML using rules in drupal?

Tags: xml, drupal, drupal-rules

I'm new in drupal and currently I have to get a way to create content from XML using the Rules module.

I managed to get the xml from a webservice and I already created the corresponding content-type with fields to show the data. After this I have no idea how to create the content node I need in rules.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not suggest doing this using just the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules).  Check out the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) which can create nodes from an XML feed.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

ps-if it works I'll mark this answer as solved.